# How to copy an image to clipboard in powershell

Tags: powershell, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of a specific part of the current window and copy it to clipboard so I can paste it in my PPT or other documents.

I am able to successfully get the image in bmp format and I unable to find a way to place it into clipboard.

This is my code so far.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
function screenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, $path) {

   $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
   $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

   $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)
   $bmp.Save($path)

   # Create data object.
   $dataObject = New-Object windows.forms.dataobject

   # Add generated strings to data object.
   $dataObject.SetData("jpg", $true, $bmp)

   # Put data object in system clipboard.
   [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetDataObject($dataObject, $true)
   [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText("Hello")

}

$bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 100, 700, 500)
screenshot $bounds "d:\screenshot.png"
```

I have tried other various ways of doing it but not able to crack it.

Even simple text is not being copied to clipboard.

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: If I had to guess, using `"jpg"` for a BMP is not helping your cause any.

Comment: I tried using bmp too without success

Answer (score 0):

All right, here we go. General approach garnered from associated forum posts plus `Clipboard` method list. Name attempts to follow the [approved verbs list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Extraneous functionality (saving to path?) trimmed as non-essential.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

function Set-ClipboardFromScreenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$Bounds) {
   $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $Bounds.width, $Bounds.height
   $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)
   $graphics.CopyFromScreen($Bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $Bounds.size)
   [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($bmp)
}

Set-ClipboardFromScreenshot ([Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 100, 700, 500))
```

Tested and verified as copying actual screenshot of proper size and presumably proper origin.